# Photoshop CC: PSD to PDF conversion problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, export, adobe-acrobat

I have a problem converting from PSD to PDF in my Photoshop. When I try to save to PDF via 'Save as > Photoshop PDF' then the PDF that I get is not editable or searchable to browsers nor to Acrobat Reader or Pro. I have a friend with the exact same version and he showed me that he doesn't have any problem.

Here is the summary of my PDF settings:

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of options in the 'prodcedure of save as>photoshop pdf', please include screenshots of your exact settings.

Comment: This is also *highly dependent* upon *how* the Photoshop file is constructed.

Comment: this the screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwNtWxyYBMo6S2tDNFpzdXRSV2s?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting live type in a PDF from Photoshop is highly dependant on what you've done with that type; so any effects etc. will cause it not to exported correctly.

In this case you're using a faux bold style on your font.

You can see this in the warning in your PDF export summary:

> Fonts used with faux bold style cannot be included in vector data.

[image]

Simple fix; don't use a faux bold style. If you want bold type you should use an actual bold font (i.e. select the style from the top right dropdown in the Character panel).

Just turn this option off:

[image]